# Is this measure on extension of $\sigma$-algebra well defined?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \xi, \mu)$ be a measure space and define:
$$\xi_\mu := \{A \in \mathcal{P} : \exists B, C \in \xi: \mu(C) = 0 \text{ and } A \,\triangle\, B\subseteq C\}$$
I already showed that $\xi_\mu$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\xi \subseteq \xi_\mu$. For $A \in \xi_\mu$ with $B, C \in \xi$ as in the definition we define:

$$\bar\mu(A) := \mu(B)$$

Now I'll need to prove that this is even well defined. Let's consider two $B_1, B_2, C_1, C_2$ with $\mu(C_1), \mu(C_2) = 0$ and:

$$A \,\triangle\, B_1 \subseteq C_1$$
$$A \,\triangle\, B_2 \subseteq C_2$$

but I'm stuck showing $\mu(B_1) = \mu(B_2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: First prove that
$$
B_1\triangle B_2\subset (A\triangle B_1)\cup(A\triangle B_2)\subset C_1\cup C_2.
$$

Comment: Perfect. I concluded $\mu(B_1) = \mu(B_1 \cup B_2) - \mu(B_2 \setminus B_1) = \mu(B_1 \cup B_2) - \mu(B_1 \setminus B_2) = \mu(B_2)$. Your hint proves the second equality, right?

Comment: Sure :) I'm glad it helped.